# The $.param( ) inverse function in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following form:

```
<form>
    <input name="foo" value="bar">
    <input name="hello" value="hello world">
</form>
```

I can use the `$.param( .. )` construct to serialize the form:

```
$.param( $('form input') )

=> foo=bar&hello=hello+world
```

How can I deserialize the above String with JavaScript and get a hash back?

For example,

```
$.magicFunction("foo=bar&hello=hello+world")

=> {'foo' : 'bar', 'hello' : 'hello world'}
```

Reference: [`jQuery.param( obj )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/#jQuery-param-obj).

Comment: Hey, I'm just adding this comment so you can see the update I did to the code, in case you're using it... I'd accidentally written it so that it only replaced the first `+`. Now it replaces all of them!

Comment: There are plugins called `QueryString`. I made one but it doesn't accept parameters, it only reads from window.location.search. I remember others that accept parameters...

Comment: refactored jquery BBQ deparam() method as NPM module without dependencies
https://www.npmjs.com/package/deparam

Comment: alexey2baranov how about refactoring deparam() without NPM as dependency? :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should use [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)'s [deparam](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) function. It's well-tested and documented.

Comment: If you don't want to get the whole BBQ plugin, the deparam function was extracted as a standalone plugin here: https://github.com/chrissrogers/jquery-deparam

Comment: Unfortunately the github page hasn't seen any updates in years, and when I tried it it does not seem compatible with the latest jQuery... Looks like what I need though.

Answer (score 31):

This is a slightly modified version of a function I wrote a while ago to do something similar.

```
var QueryStringToHash = function QueryStringToHash  (query) {
  var query_string = {};
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    pair[0] = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
    pair[1] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
  return query_string;
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought with accepted answer "this won't work with arrays". Your solution works all right.

Answer (score 21):

How about this short functional approach?

```
function parseParams(str) {
    return str.split('&').reduce(function (params, param) {
        var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function (value) {
            return decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        });
        params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
        return params;
    }, {});
}
```

Example:

```
parseParams("this=is&just=an&example") // Object {this: "is", just: "an", example: undefined}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no external dependencies.

Comment: Simple, reliable and powerful solution. Respect, sir.

Comment: For what it does it is certainly a good solution. But it does not take care of arrays or objects being passed. The url `field[][]=a&field[0][]=b&field[0][]=c` gets processed as `Object { field[][]: "a", field[0][]: "c" }` where it should be `resultobject.field[0] = Array [ "a", "b", "c" ]`. This is the behaviour as expected from PHP. @JackyLi's solution does take care of that.

Answer (score 18):

My answer:

```
function(query){
  var setValue = function(root, path, value){
    if(path.length > 1){
      var dir = path.shift();
      if( typeof root[dir] == 'undefined' ){
        root[dir] = path[0] == '' ? [] : {};
      }

      arguments.callee(root[dir], path, value);
    }else{
      if( root instanceof Array ){
        root.push(value);
      }else{
        root[path] = value;
      }
    }
  };
  var nvp = query.split('&');
  var data = {};
  for( var i = 0 ; i < nvp.length ; i++ ){
    var pair = nvp[i].split('=');
    var name = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
    var value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

    var path = name.match(/(^[^\[]+)(\[.*\]$)?/);
    var first = path[1];
    if(path[2]){
      //case of 'array[level1]' || 'array[level1][level2]'
      path = path[2].match(/(?=\[(.*)\]$)/)[1].split('][')
    }else{
      //case of 'name'
      path = [];
    }
    path.unshift(first);

    setValue(data, path, value);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! This is the exact one I need to parse the params that are being sent by JQuery in an $.ajax call. This returns the correctly nested hashes. Thanks so much, Jacky Li!

Comment: The best solution so far - It behaves *pretty* good! But when I use `JSON.stringify(geturlargs('fld[2][]=2&fld[][]=3&fld[3][]=4&fld[]=bb&fld[]=cc').fld)` I get `{"2":["2"],"3":["4"],"":"cc"}` and not `[null,null,[2],[3,4],"bb","cc"]` what I would have hoped for (this is what PHP would give me).

Comment: This is THE correct answer and please ignore all other anwers, they do not work properly

Comment: This answer is the only one that addressed my particular use case (where I've passed an object with nested key/values to jQuery's $.param, this properly hydrates those values upon retrieval).

Comment: This might need a tweak. I just noticed if query === "" this has exception at var first = path[1];, because nvp has one item in it.

Comment: Nice that it works for multiple values passed in the URL

Answer (score 9):

I am using David Dorward's answer, and realized that it doesn't behave like PHP or Ruby on Rails how they parse the params:

1) a variable is only an array if it ends with `[]`, such as `?choice[]=1&choice[]=12`, not when it is `?a=1&a=2`

2) when mulitple params exist with the same name, the later ones replaces the earlier ones, as on PHP servers (Ruby on Rails keep the first one and ignore the later ones), such as `?a=1&b=2&a=3`

So modifying David's version, I have:

```
function QueryStringToHash(query) {

  if (query == '') return null;

  var hash = {};

  var vars = query.split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    var k = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
    var v = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

    // If it is the first entry with this name
    if (typeof hash[k] === "undefined") {

      if (k.substr(k.length-2) != '[]')  // not end with []. cannot use negative index as IE doesn't understand it
        hash[k] = v;
      else
        hash[k.substr(0, k.length-2)] = [v];

    // If subsequent entry with this name and not array
    } else if (typeof hash[k] === "string") {
      hash[k] = v;  // replace it

    // If subsequent entry with this name and is array
    } else {
      hash[k.substr(0, k.length-2)].push(v);
    }
  } 
  return hash;
};
```

which is tested fairly thoroughly.

Comment: The uri spec is that ?a=1&a=2 should be an array. Ruby on Rails and PHP do not follow the actual specification.

Comment: The line where you append to the array should be `hash[k.substr(0, k.length-2)] = [v];` and `hash[k.substr(0, k.length-2)].push(v);`

Comment: Would be nice if this could be made available through npm

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe there is still some relevance in it?

Inspired by Jacky Li's good solution I tried a slight variation of my own with the objective to also be able to take care of arbitrary combinations of arrays and objects as input. I looked at how PHP would have done it and tried to get something "similar" going. Here is my code:

```
function getargs(str){
   var ret={};
   function build(urlnam,urlval,obj){ // extend the return object ...
    var i,k,o=obj, x, rx=/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, idx=[urlnam.replace(rx,'')];
    while (x=rx.exec(urlnam)) idx.push(x[1]); 
    while(true){
     k=idx.shift();
     if(k.trim()=='') {// key is empty: autoincremented index
       if (o.constructor.name=='Array') k=o.length; // for Array
       else if (o===obj ) {k=null}  // for first level property name
       else {k=-1;                                  // for Object
         for(i in o) if (+i>k) k=+i;
         k++;
       }
     }
     if(idx.length) { 
       // set up an array if the next key (idx[0]) appears to be
       // numeric or empty, otherwise set up an object:
       if (o[k]==null || typeof o[k]!='object') o[k]=isNaN(idx[0])?{}:[]; 
       o=o[k]; // move on to the next level
     }
     else { // OK, time to store the urlval in its chosen place ...
       // console.log('key',k,'val',urlval);                 
       o[k]=urlval===""?null:urlval; break; // ... and leave the while loop.
     } 
    }
    return obj;
   }
   // ncnvt: is a flag that governs the conversion of
   // numeric strings into numbers
   var ncnvt=true,i,k,p,v,argarr=[],
       ar=(str||window.location.search.substring(1)).split("&"),
       l=ar.length;
   for (i=0;i<l;i++) {if (ar[i]==="") continue;
     p=ar[i].split("=");k=decodeURIComponent(p[0]);
     v=p[1];v=(v!=null)?decodeURIComponent(v.replace(/\+/g,'%20')):'';
     if (ncnvt && v.trim()>"" && !isNaN(v)) v-=0;
     argarr.push([k,v]);  // array: key-value-pairs of all arguments
   }
   for (i=0,l=argarr.length;i<l;i++) build(argarr[i][0],argarr[i][1],ret);
   return ret;
}
```

If the function is called without the `str`-argument it will assume  `window.location.search.slice(1)` as input.

**Some examples:**

```
['a=1&a=2',                               // 1
 'x[y][0][z][]=1',                        // 2
 'hello=[%22world%22]&world=hello',       // 3
 'a=1&a=2&&b&c=3&d=&=e&',                 // 4
 'fld[2][]=2&fld[][]=3&fld[3][]=4&fld[]=bb&fld[]=cc',  // 5
 $.param({a:[[1,2],[3,4],{aa:'one',bb:'two'},[5,6]]}), // 6
 'a[]=hi&a[]=2&a[3][]=7&a[3][]=99&a[]=13',// 7
 'a[x]=hi&a[]=2&a[3][]=7&a[3][]=99&a[]=13'// 8
].map(function(v){return JSON.stringify(getargs(v));}).join('\n')
```

results in

```
{"a":2}                                    // 1
{"x":{"y":[{"z":[1]}]}}                    // 2
{"hello":"[\"world\"]","world":"hello"}    // 3
{"a":2,"b":null,"c":3,"d":null,"null":"e"} // 4 = { a: 2, b: null, c: 3, d: null, null: "e" }
{"fld":[null,null,[2],[3,4],"bb","cc"]}    // 5 
{"a":[[1,2],[3,4],{"aa":"one","bb":"two"},[5,6]]}  // 6
{"a":["hi",2,null,[7,99],13]}              // 7
{"a":{"0":2,"3":[7,99],"4":13,"x":"hi"}}   // 8
```

Whereas Jacky Li's solution would produce the outer container for `a` as a plain object

```
{a:{"0":["1","2"],"1":["3","4"],"2":["5","6"]}} // 6: JackyLi's output
```

`getargs()` looks at the first given index for any level to determine whether this level will be an object (non-numeric index) or an array (numeric or empty), thus resulting in the output as shown in the listing bove (no. 6).

If the current object is an array then `null`s get inserted wherever necessary to represent empty positions. Arrays are always consecutively numbered and 0-based).

Note, that in the example no. 8 the "autoincrement" for empty indices still works, even though we are dealing with an object now and not an array.

As far as I have tested it, my `getargs()` behaves pretty much identically to Chriss Roger's great jQuery `$.deparam()` [plugin](https://github.com/chrissrogers/jquery-deparam/blob/master/jquery-deparam.js) mentioned in the accepted answer. The main difference is that `getargs` runs without jQuery and that it *does* autoincrement in objects while `$.deparam()` will *not* do that:

```
JSON.stringify($.deparam('a[x]=hi&a[]=2&a[3][]=7&a[3][]=99&a[]=13').a);
```

results in

```
{"3":["7","99"],"x":"hi","undefined":"13"}
```

In `$.deparam()` the index `[]` is interpreted as an `undefined` instead of an autoincremented numerical index.

Comment: thanks for this great function. However I noticed that if you use number as key in array, e.g. like ' ?a[5][]=x ' then key is used as number when creating object and thus it creates 5 empty elements in my case. It should treat numeric key as string, and thus create object with "5" (with quotes) as key and x as value. I could force url to be ' ?a["5"][]=x ' but this is ugly...

Comment: @Andrew: This was a deliberate design decision on my part: As far as I remember, Jack's solution will behave more in the way you expect it. I introduced the line `o[k]=isNaN(idx[0])?{}:[];` with the intention of creating an array, whenever I encounter a numeric index as the first one given for a new object. Otherwise I will make a generic object. It is up to you to modify that part of the code to better suit your needs. I. e. something like `o[k]={}` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks. P.S. you should definitely remove console.log in the middle of your function ;)

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, just commented it out. Must have overlooked it when I posted the code.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you could create a new jQuery function:

```
jQuery.unparam = function (value) {
    var
    // Object that holds names => values.
    params = {},
    // Get query string pieces (separated by &)
    pieces = value.split('&'),
    // Temporary variables used in loop.
    pair, i, l;

    // Loop through query string pieces and assign params.
    for (i = 0, l = pieces.length; i < l; i++) {
        pair = pieces[i].split('=', 2);
        // Repeated parameters with the same name are overwritten. Parameters
        // with no value get set to boolean true.
        params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = (pair.length == 2 ?
            decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : true);
    }

    return params;
};
```

Comment: I don't like this function. Why should parameter with no value should get the value of 'true'? Why not null? I think this design decision can lead to very subtle bugs. Also, why not handle the situation where parameter can have multiple values instead of selecting the 'last' value? Solution posted by David is much better.

Comment: It is `true` so that one can check `if (params.redirect)` or similar. If you want to differ between `true` and other value, you would use `if (params.redirect === true)`. A `null` value wouldn't help in any way that I can think of. The reason I didn't do it like David is because I value consistency over flexibility. With his method I have to check if the value is a string or an array to use its value. In my opinion, it should always be a string (the `true` value converts to `'true'` which I think is fine), or always be an array. I chose string.

Comment: By that account, if it was params.delete, it would be set to true and I will do something harmful. As you can see, coming up with example is easy. 'null' clearly specifies that no value exists and the decision is left to the caller what how he wants to interpret it. 

About multiple values, look at it this way. By eating up, you are making sure that either caller will spend time debugging why he is getting only one value OR later on come and modify the code. By returning the array upfront, caller will immediately know how to handle them. Discarding information is never good, IMHO.

Comment: If the URL is `/abc?delete` then I would expect there to be an entry for `delete`. I don't see how that is different? I don't even see how you can prefer the other code for this reason, because that code will set the value to the string `'undefined'` which is not better. And as for multiple values it's a case of simplicity vs. flexibility. I rarely see the use of multiple values in query strings, but if you want them, always return an array with 1+ values. Never mix the return type; then you *will* have to spend time to debug because what was usually a string could suddenly be an array.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think there is a silver bullet. I took your code and modified it a bit, removed the boolean values, added parsing of array-parameters. ?foo[]=1&foo[]=2 => foo : ["1","2"]

Comment: Of course, I just want people to be aware of the dangers of inconsistent magic. It's so overlooked that even the best aren't prepared for it: http://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name%5B%5D=arrays Usually it just messes up the result for the user, but it could have other consequences.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to him http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

Pretty easy :D

```
function params_unserialize(p){
var ret = {},
    seg = p.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&'),
    len = seg.length, i = 0, s;
for (;i<len;i++) {
    if (!seg[i]) { continue; }
    s = seg[i].split('=');
    ret[s[0]] = s[1];
}
return ret;}
```

Comment: This do not work with select boxes with multiple options, because it only keep last selected.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see what is the point you are referring to in the comment. The function referenced here is to unserialize/parse an URI with params like `?something=1&param2=value2` into an array. What do you mean with "do not work with select boxes with multiple options"?

Answer (score 5):

This is really old question, but as i have coming - other people may coming to this post, and i want to a bit refresh this theme. Today no need to make custom solutions - there is [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface.

```
var paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//Iterate the search parameters.
for (let p of searchParams) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

The only one limitation i know - this feature not supported in IE / Edge.

Comment: Unfortunately not support by IE, as per usual, in case you need to support this browser.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my JavaScript implementation which I use in a server-side [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) page ([demo](http://jsbin.com/lopokohanu)):

```
// Transforms a query string in the form x[y][0][z][]=1 into {x:{y:[{z:[1]}]}}
function parseJQueryParams(p) {
    var params = {};
    var pairs = p.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
        var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        var indices = [];
        var name = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]),
            value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);

        var name = name.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, 
            function(k, idx) { indices.push(idx); return ""; });

        indices.unshift(name);
        var o = params;

        for (var j=0; j<indices.length-1; j++) {
            var idx = indices[j];
            var nextIdx = indices[j+1];
            if (!o[idx]) {
                if ((nextIdx == "") || (/^[0-9]+$/.test(nextIdx)))
                    o[idx] = [];
                else
                    o[idx] = {};
            }
            o = o[idx];
        }

        idx = indices[indices.length-1];
        if (idx == "") {
            o.push(value);
        }
        else {
            o[idx] = value;
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: So far the best I found for nested arrays

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution, which behaves like the .Net function `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

In the result, the query string parameters are store in properties as lists of values, so that `qsObj["param"]` will be the same as calling `GetValues("param")` in .Net.

I hope you like it. JQuery not required.

```
var parseQueryString = function (querystring) {
    var qsObj = new Object();
    if (querystring) {
        var parts = querystring.replace(/\?/, "").split("&");
        var up = function (k, v) {
            var a = qsObj[k];
            if (typeof a == "undefined") {
                qsObj[k] = [v];
            }
            else if (a instanceof Array) {
                a.push(v);
            }
        };
        for (var i in parts) {
            var part = parts[i];
            var kv = part.split('=');
            if (kv.length == 1) {
                var v = decodeURIComponent(kv[0] || "");
                up(null, v);
            }
            else if (kv.length > 1) {
                var k = decodeURIComponent(kv[0] || "");
                var v = decodeURIComponent(kv[1] || "");
                up(k, v);
            }
        }
    }
    return qsObj;
};
```

Here is how to use it:

```
var qsObj = parseQueryString("a=1&a=2&&b&c=3&d=&=e&");
```

To preview the result in the console juste type in:

```
JSON.stringify(qsObj)
```

Output:

```
"{"a":["1","2"],"null":["","b",""],"c":["3"],"d":[""],"":["e"]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a beautiful one-liner over at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-query-params-object/) (original source from [Nicholas Ortenzio](https://github.com/youbastard/jquery.getQueryParameters)):

```
function getQueryParameters(str) {
    return (str || document.location.search).replace(/(^\?)/,'').split("&").map(function(n){return n = n.split("="),this[n[0]] = n[1],this}.bind({}))[0];
}
```

The really clever part is how it uses the anonymous function's `this` object, adding a key/value pair for each of the queries in the string. That said, there's some room for improvement. I've modified it a bit below, with the following changes:

1. Added handling of empty strings and non-string input.
2. Handled URI-encoded strings (`%40`->`@`, etc).
3. Removed the default use of `document.location.search` when the input was empty.
4. Changed the name, made it more readable, added comments.

```
function deparam(str) {
    // Uses an empty 'this' to build up the results internally
    function splitQuery(query) {
        query = query.split('=').map(decodeURIComponent);
        this[query[0]] = query[1];
        return this;
    }

    // Catch bad input
    if (!str || !(typeof str === 'string' || str instanceof String))
        return {};

    // Split the string, run splitQuery on each piece, and return 'this'
    var queries = str.replace(/(^\?)/,'').split('&');
    return queries.map(splitQuery.bind({}))[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
// convert query string to json object
var queryString = "cat=3&sort=1&page=1";

queryString
    .split("&")
    .forEach((item) => {
        const prop = item.split("=");
        filter[prop[0]] = prop[1];
    });

console.log(queryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version in Coffeescript. 
Also works for url like 
`http://localhost:4567/index.html?hello=[%22world%22]&world=hello#/home`

```
getQueryString: (url)->
    return null if typeof url isnt 'string' or url.indexOf("http") is -1

    split = url.split "?"

    return null if split.length < 2 
    path = split[1]

    hash_pos = path.indexOf "#"
    path = path[0...hash_pos] if hash_pos isnt -1

    data = path.split "&"
    ret = {}
    for d in data
      [name, val] = d.split "=" 
      name = decodeURIComponent name
      val = decodeURIComponent val
      try 
        ret[name] = JSON.parse val
      catch error
        ret[name] = val
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple & compact one if you only want to quickly get the parameters from a GET request:

```
function httpGet() {
    var a={},b,i,q=location.search.replace(/^\?/,"").split(/\&/);
    for(i in q) if(q[i]) {b=q[i].split("=");if(b[0]) a[b[0]]=
    decodeURIComponent(b[1]).replace(/\+/g," ");} return a;
}
```

It converts

```
something?aa=1&bb=2&cc=3
```

into an object like

```
{aa:1,bb:2,cc:3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creates a serialized representation of an array or object (can be used as URL query string for AJAX requests).

```
<button id='param'>GET</button> 
<div id="show"></div>
<script>
  $('#param').click(function () {
    var personObj = new Object();
    personObj.firstname = "vishal"
    personObj.lastname = "pambhar";
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=$.param(`personObj`));
  });
</script>
output:firstname=vishal&lastname=pambhar
```

Comment: Code without explainations isnt welcome. Could be please go ahead and explain your code?

Comment: Creates a serialize representation of an array or object (can be used as URL query string for AJAX requests)

Comment: Please add explainations directly in your answer, by editing it. Not in comments though.

Answer (score -1):

answers could use a bit of **jQuery** elegance:

```
(function($) {
var re = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
var decodeRE = /\+/g; // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
var decode = function (str) {return decodeURIComponent( str.replace(decodeRE, " ") );};
$.parseParams = function(query) {
    var params = {}, e;
    while ( e = re.exec(query) ) {
        var k = decode( e[1] ), v = decode( e[2] );
        if (k.substring(k.length - 2) === '[]') {
            k = k.substring(0, k.length - 2);
            (params[k] || (params[k] = [])).push(v);
        }
        else params[k] = v;
    }
    return params;
};
})(jQuery);
```

fork at https://gist.github.com/956897

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `.serializeArray()` ([Link](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)) of jQuery itself. This function returns an array of key-value pair. Result example:

```
[
  { name: "id", value: "1" },
  { name: "version", value: "100" }
]
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. He wants to turn a string into a hash. serializeArray takes a form and returns an array.