# Non-ajax GET/POST using jQuery (plugin?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is one of those situations where I feel like I'm missing a crucial keyword to find the answer on Google...

I have a bag of parameters and I want to make the browser navigate to a GET URL with the parameters. Being a jQuery user, I know that if I wanted to make an ajax request, I would simply do:

```
$.getJSON(url, params, fn_handle_result);
```

But sometimes I don't want to use ajax. I just want to submit the parameters and get a page back.

Now, I know I can loop the parameters and manually construct a GET URL. For POST, I can dynamically create a form, populate it with fields and submit. But I'm sure somebody has written a plugin that does this already. Or maybe I missed something and you can do it with core jQuery.

So, does anybody know of such a plugin?

EDIT: Basically, what I want is to write:

```
$.goTo(url, params);
```

And optionally

```
$.goTo(url, params, "POST");
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

jQuery Plugin seemed to work great until I tried it on IE8. I had to make this slight modification to get it to work on IE:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        getGo: function(url, params) {
            document.location = url + '?' + $.param(params);
        },
        postGo: function(url, params) {
            var $form = $("<form>")
                .attr("method", "post")
                .attr("action", url);
            $.each(params, function(name, value) {
                $("<input type='hidden'>")
                    .attr("name", name)
                    .attr("value", value)
                    .appendTo($form);
            });
            $form.appendTo("body");
            $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Excellent, but I was a little in the dark on how to use this for posting the input values of another form on the page. In the end I used it with the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/javascript-jquery-param-inverse-function#1131658 unparam function by blixt like so: $.postGo('/my/post/handler', jQuery.unparam($('#myform').serialize()));

Comment: Note: the jQuery plugin Dustin's referring to is by itsadok (see below).  That confused me at first.  ;-)

Comment: nice! Also if you want to support arrays passed as values, then you have to update `postGo` method (`getGo` works ok already): add check `if (value instanceof Array)` inside `function(name, value) {` of `each` loop and in case value IS array - iterate over it, appending inputs with value `values[i]`. In case value IS NOT an array - use already present code.

Comment: @JamesMcCormack This solution is most useful if you don't have a form beforehand. If you already have a form, then most of the time you can just [`.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) it. Using `serialize` then `unparam` is a bit roundabout.

Answer (score 20):

Here's what I ended up doing, using the tip from redsquare:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        doGet: function(url, params) {
            document.location = url + '?' + $.param(params);
        },
        doPost: function(url, params) {
            var $form = $("<form method='POST'>").attr("action", url);
            $.each(params, function(name, value) {
                $("<input type='hidden'>")
                    .attr("name", name)
                    .attr("value", value)
                    .appendTo($form);
            });
            $form.appendTo("body");
            $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$.doPost("/mail/send.php", {
    subject: "test email",
    body: "This is a test email sent with $.doPost"
});
```

Any feedback would be welcome.

**Update:** see dustin's answer for a version that works in IE8

Comment: without $form.appendTo("body"); it will not work in IE9. Thanks ! I was having a problem with this

Answer (score 12):

It is not clear from the question if you have a random bunch of values you want to pass on the querystring or is it form values.

For form values just use the [.serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) function to construct the querystring.

e.g

```
var qString = $('#formid').serialize();
document.location = 'someUrl' + '?' + serializedForm
```

If you have a random bunch of values you can construct an object and use the [.param](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.param#obj) utility method.

e.g

```
 var params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
 var str = jQuery.param( params );
 console.log( str )
 // prints width=1680&height=1050
 // document.location = 'someUrl' + '?' + str
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI for anyone doing the doPost for rails 3, you need to add in the CSRF token, Adding the following to the answer should do that...

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$("<input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value='" + token + "'/>").appendTo($form);
```

Comment: Yes, certain other server-side technologies (Drupal and Django come to mind) will require some hidden security-related fields like this too.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the above except it will handle Array parameters being passed to MVC

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        getGo: function(url, params, traditional) {
            /// <summary>
            ///     Perform a GET at url with specified params passed as part of the query string.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="url"></param>
            /// <param name="params"></param>
            /// <param name="traditional">Boolean:  Specify true for traditional serialization.</param>
            document.location = url + '?' + $.param(params, traditional);
        },
        postGo: function (url, params) {
            /// <summary>
            ///     Perform a POST at url with the specified params as part of a form object.
            ///     If a parameter is an array then it will submit it as multiple attributes so MVC will see it as an array
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="url" type="string"></param>
            /// <param name="params" type="Object"></param>
            var $form = $("<form>").attr("method", "post").attr("action", url);
            $.each(params, function (name, value) {
                if (value.length != null && value.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        $("<input type='hidden'>").attr("name", name + '[' + i + ']').attr("value", value[i]).appendTo($form);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("<input type='hidden'>").attr("name", name).attr("value", value).appendTo($form);
                }
            });
            $form.appendTo("body");
            $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: ++, but note that (at least as of MVC 6 - not sure about earlier versions) you needn't modify the `name` value with an index - multiple elements of the very same name will do to be recognized as an array. Also, perhaps substituting `$.isArray(value)` for `value.length != null && value.length > 0` makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Good job itsadok! If you want a invisible form put it into hidden DIV:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        doGet: function(url, params) {
            document.location = url + '?' + $.param(params);
        },
        doPost: function(url, params) {
            var $div = $("<div>").css("display", "none");
            var $form = $("<form method='POST'>").attr("action", url);
            $.each(params, function(name, value) {
                $("<input type='hidden'>")
                    .attr("name", name)
                    .attr("value", value)
                    .appendTo($form);
            });
            $form.appendTo($div);
            $div.appendTo("body");
            $form.submit();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, or you can just set the <form> to `display: none`.  A form with only hidden fields shouldn't display anything, however - except maybe a little empty space from the margin/padding (in certain browsers).

Answer (score -5):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to cover your POST requirement, as setting document.location will always result in a GET request. Here's a possible solution, although I'm not sure jQuery permits loading the entire contents of the page like this:

```
$.post(url, params, function(data) {
  $(document).html(data);
}, "html");
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you.  But a .post is AJAX.  He wanted non-AJAX so it would actually change the page.