# When I press submit button there is no postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I am stuck in creating a submit form.

Model Email.cs:

```
 using System.Web;

 namespace MySite.Models
 {
    public class Email
    {
       public string From { get; set; }
       public string Subject { get; set; }
       public string body { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Controller CommunicationController.cs:

```
namespace MySite.Controllers
{
    public class CommunicationController : Controller
     { 
        public ActionResult SendEmail() {

        Email email = new Email();
        return View(email);
     }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult SendEmail(Email email)
       {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
           { 

            }

            return View(email);
        }
    }
}
```

View SendEmail.cshtml:

```
@model MySite.Models.Email

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "SendEmail";
 }

<h2>@Html.Label("Send email")</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
   <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.Label("From")
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From)

  </div>  <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Subject")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject)

  </div>   <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.Label("Body")
   </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.body)

   </div>

   <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SendEmail" />
}
```

When I press submit, the event never gets fired. In the controller if I press 'go to view' then it goes to SendEmail view. I have no idea whats happenning. I tried to debug but the [HttpPost] controller never gets fired.

Here is what I get from browser, I don't see action

```
<form method="post" action="/" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" value="ZktM_I7fzdlcNme4YVEcNNpnFFmQu1cpAuTXarO_V4w-7bPmpHkaLRfNY3cXGMYy7wkRgSJWW‌​SkS8lp5vdRimFrNCgqk0Jfdr4v7Zc3V2pg1" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="From" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="From">
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <div class="editor-field">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SendEmail">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript that might be doing something? A form not submitting is not an MVC problem.. it is a markup/javascript/browser problem.

Comment: Do you need a HttpGet attribute on your first method?

Comment: Is an HTTP request being sent when you press submit? Use your browser developer tools to find out what's happening.

Comment: Here is what I get from browser, I don't see action

<form method="post" action="/" novalidate="novalidate">

<input type="hidden" value="ZktM_I7fzdlcNme4YVEcNNpnFFmQu1cpAuTXarO_V4w-7bPmpHkaLRfNY3cXGMYy7wkRgSJWWSkS8lp5vdRimFrNCgqk0Jfdr4v7Zc3V2pg1" name="__RequestVerificationToken">

<div class="editor-label">
<div class="editor-field">
<input id="From" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="From">
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
<div class="editor-field">
<div class="editor-label">
<div class="editor-field">
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SendEmail">
</form>

Comment: @LakpaSherpa Don't add code blobs like that into comments; they're not built to display that much code properly. I moved it into your question, which you can do by using the Edit link.

Comment: @Tieson: sorry about at.

Comment: @Simon: Yaah it was my Javascript that was creating an error. I removed the Javascript I wrote and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName",
                    FormMethod.Post))
        {
           //form UI

           <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SendEmail" />
        }
```

## Edit

You can also try this:

```
<a onclick="$('#formId').submit();">Submit</a>
or
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Changed to 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Communication", FormMethod.Post)), but still its not firing the event.

Comment: Place the submit button inside the form.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174235/submit-button-not-working-as-expected?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use the basic helper, so I could be wrong, but I believe the default method you get from

```
Html.BeginForm()
```

is a GET. So, you probably want to use

```
Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Communication", FormMethod.Post, new { /* html attributes */ })
```

Then, to test whether you're actually hitting the controller, add this inside the action:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Action was called!");
```

That will show up as an error in your ValidationSummary, which is okay, since we're just debugging here.

Comment: The default method from the helper is POST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party...

Try replacing:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SendEmail" />
```

With:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="submitButton value="SendEmail" />
```

Let us know if this works, or if you found another solution! :)