# Posting to an Index page when an action link is clicked in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor, filter

Currently I have a page that looks like this.

[image: Page Layout]

and I have an action link on my home page that looks like this

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Off Site Inventory Order (OSI)", "Index", "SalesOrders", new { type = "OSI"}, null) </li>
```

That link however does not do what I want it to do so I was hoping to get some help.
When I click that click on the home page I want it to direct me to that page I showed you above however I want it to be filtered by the order type of 'OSI' so that it automatically looks like this

[[image: filtered[2]]

where it filters the page to OSI orders instead.

Here is my salesOrderController GET method

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? wholesalerID)
        {


            int perpage = 50;

            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
            if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = TempData["ErrorMessage"];

            var salesOrders = db.SalesOrders
                .Include(s => s.Customers)
                .Include(s => s.Partners)
                .Include(s => s.Wholesaler)
                .Include(s => s.RnD)
                .Include(s => s.ECommerce)
                .Include(s => s.Direct)
                .Include(s => s.Marketing)
                .Where(x => x.deleted.Equals(false))
                .OrderBy(x => x.SalesOrderStatus).ThenByDescending(x => x.ID);

            ViewBag.CanSeeCost = false;
            if (IGT.canAccess(IGT.userId, AccessRestrictions.ModifySalesOrder, false))
            {
                ViewBag.CanSeeCost = true;

                var total = salesOrders.Where(s => ((s.SalesOrderStatus == SOStatus.Released) || (s.SalesOrderStatus == SOStatus.Shipped) || s.SalesOrderStatus == SOStatus.Close) && !s.deleted);

                ViewBag.TotalRetail = total.Sum(x => x.totalRetail);
                ViewBag.TotalShipping = total.Sum(x => x.totalShipped);
                ViewBag.TotalRemaining = ViewBag.TotalRetail - ViewBag.TotalShipping;
                if (total.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoCharge) != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.TotalRetailNoCharge = total.Where(x => x.NoCharge).Sum(x => x.totalRetail);
                    ViewBag.TotalShippingNoCharge = total.Where(x => x.NoCharge).Sum(x => x.totalShipped);
                    ViewBag.TotalRemainingNoCharge = ViewBag.TotalRetailNoCharge - ViewBag.TotalShippingNoCharge;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.TotalRetailNoCharge = 0;
                    ViewBag.TotalShippingNoCharge = 0;
                    ViewBag.TotalRemainingNoCharge = 0;
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.customerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.customerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "customerID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.Retailers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.partnerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.partnerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "partnerID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.Dealers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.wholesalerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.wholesalerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "wholesalerID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.RnDs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.rndID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.rndID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "rndID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.ECommerces = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.eID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.eID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "eID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.Directs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.directID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.directID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "directID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.Marketings = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.marketingID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.marketingID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "marketingID", "CustomerName");
            ViewBag.PO = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => !x.deleted).Where(x => x.CustomerPONumber != null), "CustomerPONumber", "CustomerPONumber");

            ViewBag.orderby = "true";
            ViewBag.sortOrder = "status";

            ViewBag.wholesalerID = wholesalerID;

            ViewBag.page = 1;
            ViewBag.totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)salesOrders.Count() / perpage);


            return View(salesOrders.Take(perpage).ToList());
        }
```

But not sure of how to do the post, I have a filter method that works for all the filters on the screen but not sure if I just manipulate that, or create a index post method or what

In response to the answer I received, I made it resemble my filter method so now it looks like this

```
  if (type == "OSI")
            {
                ordertype = 3; // OSI Order Id
                ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.customerID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.customerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "customerID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.Retailers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.partnerID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.partnerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "partnerID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.Dealers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.wholesalerID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.wholesalerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "wholesalerID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.RnDs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.rndID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.rndID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "rndID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.ECommerces = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.eID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.eID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "eID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.Directs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.directID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.directID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "directID", "CustomerName");
                ViewBag.Marketings = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.marketingID != null && !x.deleted && x.OrderType == (SOType)ordertype).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.marketingID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "marketingID", "CustomerName");
            }
            else
            {
               ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.customerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.customerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "customerID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.Retailers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.partnerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.partnerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "partnerID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.Dealers = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.wholesalerID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.wholesalerID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "wholesalerID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.RnDs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.rndID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.rndID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "rndID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.ECommerces = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.eID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.eID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "eID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.Directs = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.directID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.directID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "directID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.Marketings = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.marketingID != null && !x.deleted).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName).Select(x => new { x.marketingID, x.CustomerName }).Distinct(), "marketingID", "CustomerName");
               ViewBag.PO = new SelectList(db.SalesOrders.Where(x => !x.deleted).Where(x => x.CustomerPONumber != null), "CustomerPONumber", "CustomerPONumber");
            }
            ViewBag.orderby = "true";
            ViewBag.sortOrder = "status";

            ViewBag.wholesalerID = wholesalerID;
            ViewBag.type = type;

            ViewBag.page = 1;
            ViewBag.totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)salesOrders.Count() / perpage);


            return View(salesOrders.Take(perpage).ToList());
        }
```

Comment: can you post the SalesOrdersController code?

Comment: nikib3ro's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449807/mvc-make-action-link-perform-a-submit/29155696#29155696) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC make action link perform a submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449807/mvc-make-action-link-perform-a-submit)

Comment: @CaioCésarS.Leonardi Okay I posted it, but let me know if you need more details

Comment: @ZachPerry not really. But maybe I'm just not understanding it right. I'm new to MVC so excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

So, your Index method is missing the 'type' parameter and how to sort it if you pass this parameter.
With that 'Html.ActionLink' you're using, your controller should be like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? wholesalerID, string type)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) {
        //APPLY YOUR LOGIC TO ORDER BY ANY TYPE YOU PASS IN THIS PARAMETER, LIKE 'OSI'
    }
    else {
        //REGULAR ORDERING ALREADY IN USE
    }

    ...

    return View(salesOrders.Take(perpage).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caio, I tried to make it resemble my filter method  with the suggestion you gave but it does not work. I posted what I tried with your suggestion in my original questions so maybe you can take a look and see if something is wrong. Thanks