# MVC3 Html.ActionLink Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, html.actionlink

I have an MVC3 C#.NET web app and need to call a view using Html.ActionLink.  I can't tell from the documentation if I can specify the POST or GET.  Below is my HTML, is there a way to specify GET or POST?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Edit", "Subtask", 
                        new {Id = ViewBag.Id, Command="CreateHourEntry"}, null)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a post use Ajax.ActionLink but be aware it's an Ajax post. You could easily use jquery to cause your existing link to cause a form post but this functionality is not included in Html.ActionLink.

See 
[ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

Answer (score 6):

HTML hyperlinks send GETs.

To POST, you need to use a form.
<sub>or some Javascript</sub>

Comment: Use `@using (Html.BeginForm(...))`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Ajax.ActionLink where you can specify POST or GET

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Edit", "Subtask",
                  new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="Post"})
```