# Sending Html.ActionLink to post action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible using `Html.ActionLink` send request to `HttpPost` action on mvc controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 Html.ActionLink Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421074/mvc3-html-actionlink-post)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

Comment: Why would you want that? A POST action has consequences and that's why we let the user access them through forms and not links. If someone takes the URL produced by your action link, obfuscates it and sends it to a user of your application, it could have bad unintended consequences if that user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

"You can't use an ActionLink because that just renders an anchor tag.
You can use a JQuery AJAX post, see http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post
or just call the form's submit method with or without JQuery (which would be non-AJAX), perhaps in the onclick event of whatever control takes your fancy."

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049191/4337413