# MVC 4 ActionLink Dictionary htmlAttributes doesn't work

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I hope this is just a bug but figured maybe it was just me.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", "Test",
  new { id = 1 },
  new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "ui-btn-test" }, { "data-icon", "gear" } })
```

This does work but if I wanted to add further attributes I have to do it manually!

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", "Test",
  new { id = 1 },
  new { @class="ui-btn-test", data_icon="gear", data_new_attr="someextra" })
```

The first doesn't work anymore and I need this one to work. The second works but don't care that it does, because I'm trying to add more attributes, object will not work unless told differently.

Comment: What's the question?  The second way is the preferred way to specify `htmlAttributes`.

Comment: In MVC 4 the first my preferred way doesn't work correctly. I get something like this as the attributes.               <a Comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]" Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="/Home">Home</a>

Comment: Why would you want to do it the first way.  The second way works, is accepted practice, and is easier to read.

Comment: I thought, I explained myself. The reason is for the ability to add more attributes at runtime. Beside's it is a method in which is depicted in the documentation as an acceptable parameter, so why am I having trouble with using the method described?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of the provided `ActionLink` helper methods accept parameters like you're specifying. The only ones that take a parameter of type IDictionary for the html attributes expect a RouteValueDictionary for the route values. As it is, you're currently calling a function that is treating your dictionary as an anonymous object

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Tesz", "Test",
new RouteValueDictionary(new {id = 1}),
new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "ui-btn-test" }, { "data-icon", "gear" } })
```

Or implement your own extension method.

Comment: That worked out great! I was about to implement my own extension method, but didn't want to rewrite all my action links.