# @Html.ActionLink calling Post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, get

I have a `@HTML.ActionLink` in my Razor view and I'd like for it to call a `Post` action method rather than a `Get`  one.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to invoke POST action, put this link inside form which uses POST action, or use ajax version. You can find some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bootstrap you can easily make a button look like a link by applying the btn-link class, for example

```
<input type="submit" name="ActionType" value="Edit" class="col-md-1 btn btn-link" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Normal ActionLinks will be normal links. Either you have to use a form (with method being post of coorse) and have a link sumbit it. Or you could add in a but of javascript and a nice extension.

Have a look at http://dr2ab.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/linkbuttons-in-mvc-razor/

Might be something for you.