# Create hyperlink (anchor tag) in MVC to post data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a fairly simple scenario

I have an action method in my controller with syntax like that

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Consignment(string txtConsNo, string isReferenceTracking)
    {}
```

Not in a page I need to create an hyperlink in application which needs to access this action method. I am using HTML.ActionLink method to create hyperlink like this

```
        @Html.ActionLink((string)item.RDC_CONSNO, "Consignment", "Tracking", new { txtConsNo = (string)item.RDC_CONSNO, rdbConsNo = "" }, null)
```

But it creates the link like this

```
http://localhost:3412/Tracking/Consignment?txtConsNo=100245506
```

How should I go around this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to change?

Comment: @mattytommo The link that has been created is passing argument in querystring but I want to post the data

Comment: it isn't possible to post from an action link. If you want to post, you need a submit button, then you can style that to look like a link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing from your use of `item` instead of a model that you're rendering the links in a loop? In any case, I'd suggest adding a form and having the link post it; the link(s) would be like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    (string)item.RDC_CONSNO,
    "Consignment", 
    "Tracking",
    new { @class = "consignmentLink" });
```

...then after the loop (if there is one) you put in a form and some wire-up JavaScript, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Consignment", "Tracking"))
{
    @:<input type="hidden" id="txtConsNo" name="txtConsNo" />
}

$("a.consignmentLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $consignmentNumberInput = $("#txtConsNo");
    $consignmentNumberInput.val($(this).text());
    $consignmentNumberInput[0].form.submit();
});
```

To populate your action's `isReferenceTracking` parameter you could add another hidden field and have that value as a data- attribute on each link.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have two options....

1. **Remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute (preferred in my opinion)**
2. **Use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post: $.post()**

Here is how to do the jquery approach (if necessary)

**The Html:**

```
<a href="#" class="postToConsignment" 
            data-consno="@item.RDC_CONSNO">@item.RDC_CONSNO.ToString()</a>
```

**The javascript (which needs to be in your view):**

```
$(function(){
    $('.postToConsignment').on('click', function(e){
        // Stop links normal behaviour
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the url to post to
        var url = '@Url.Action("Consignment", "Controller")';

        //Get consNo
        var consNo = $(this.data('consno');

        $.post(url, new { txtConsNo: consNo}, function(data) {
            //Deal with the result (i.e. the data param)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use a button:
for example in *asp core syntax*:

```
//some other tags
 <form method="post">
      <input asp-for="YourModelPropertyOrYourMethodInputName"
      value="@TheValue" type="hidden" />
      <button type="submit" class="link-button" formaction="/TheDestinationController/TheDestinationActionMethod">
      @(TextValue) 
      </button>
  </form>
```