# @Html.ActionLink is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, actionlink

I have a orchard project, where I have created a module in MVC. I want to pass the id of particular user to controller using @Html.ActionLink but it not calling controller. Here is my code:

In view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("100111", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = 101 }, null)
//also tried,
@Html.ActionLink("102829", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = 1, area = "OnlineShopping" },null)
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
        {
            _shoppingCart.Add(id, 1);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    [Themed]  
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Create a new shape using the "New" property of IOrchardServices.
        var shape = _services.New.ShoppingCart();

        // Return a ShapeResult
        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
    }
```

Comment: You may want to remove `[HttpPost]`. It is not calling the controller action because of `[HttpPost]` and clicking on anchor tag actually does a `get`. So try remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute decoration from your `AddToCart` action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not calling the action method because of `[HttpPost]` and clicking on anchor tag actually does a `Get`. So try remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute decoration from your `AddToCart` action.

```
    [HttpPost]//<--Remove this
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        _shoppingCart.Add(id, 1);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)

> You can't use an ActionLink because that just renders an anchor tag.
>   You can use a JQuery AJAX post, see
>   http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post or just call the form's submit
>   method with or without JQuery (which would be non-AJAX), perhaps in
>   the onclick event of whatever control takes your fancy.