# Html.BeginForm and POST method without button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, post, actionlink, html.beginform

I have found the answer to the question "how to execute POST method using hyperlink (actionlink) instead of button" in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method/39175246#39175246) topic.

I have used form's submit method in this way - looks straightforward:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Area", new { id = item.id }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <tr>
        ...
        <td>

        <a href="#" onclick="$('#sbmt').trigger('click'); return false">Delete</a>
        <input id="sbmt" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden" />

        </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Typical declaration without button declaration

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();">Delete</a>
```

will not work.

The questions are:

1/ Is it possible to do the same operation but without hiding the button? I mean I don't want to use (and hide) button in my code at all.

2/ What are pros and cons of the solution listed above?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible without button.One of the way is Just simply giving id to your form like

   ```
   using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Area", new { id = item.id }, FormMethod.Post,new {id="frm"}))
   {

   }
   and then 
   <a href="javascript:$('frm').submit();" class="login-button"></a>
   ```

and if not jquery then

```
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById("frm").submit();" class="login-button"></a>
```

2. What is the problem with button I don't know. I can not see any cons except dirty coding(bad way) to submit a form.