# ActionLink with httpPost on same controller in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.6

I have a login form with "forgot password" link.
On login submit I am calling some other action while on "forgot password" link I am calling some different action:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "ForgotPassword", "Login",  Model , new { @onclick = "return ValidateUsername();" })
```

What I need is to send it as POST instead of GET.

What I have was a ASP.NET WebForm solution which I have almost completely converted into ASP.NET MVC. One place I was using LinkButton. That is the only bottle neck remains.

---

**Edit:**

Now I am using following JavaScript

```
$("a.anchor").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This will stop default behavior
    var validate = ValidateUsername();
    if (validate) {
        //alert(document.getElementById('usernameTextBox').value);

        var str = document.getElementById('usernameTextBox').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/SSOMVC/Generic/ForgotPassword",
            data: "data",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (resultData) {
                document.getElementById("usererror").textContent = resultData;
            },
            failure: function (error) {
            }
        });
    }
});

 @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", null, null, Model, new { @class = "anchor" })


  public class GenericController : Controller
    {


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string data)
        {
           ....
            return Content(callResponse);
        }
    }
```

Don't know why I am always getting data as null in the controller.

Comment: I don't think you can even do that with actionlink; if you can it'll be in one of the overloads

Comment: you can read this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method

Comment: The question is Not clear  'Model ' you can pass in  Model  in directly in ActionLink

Comment: Model was not passing in the action that's why i have passed it

Comment: You need a `<form>` to make a POST

Comment: What form Stephen. in my Ravor view there is already a for with 
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginWithPassword", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{....

Comment: Then You should make separate form and convert this link into submit button. Then add hidden input with username and copy the value from previous form. But i would advise to make such form on separte site.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but at a minimum, you need to change your data option to `data: { data : str }`; $.ajax will take care of serializing that correctly. Also, if you're using jQuery, then be consistent: `document.getElementById('usernameTextBox').value` would be `$('#usernameTextBox').val()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionLink is converted into anchor tag in MVC. An anchor tag by default sends a GET Request.

To make a Post request, you can use Ajax post call in jquery.

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "ForgotPassword", "Login",  Model , new { @onclick = "return ValidateUsername();" }, new { @class="anchor"})

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("a.anchor").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // This will stop default behavior
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<your classname/methodname>",
      data: <your data>,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData){
          alert("Call Complete");
      },
      failure: funciton(error){
}
});
    });    

</script>
```

Comment: This is the only way brother. MVC has to follow Underlying technologies. Allowing Anchorlinks to send post by default would break the rules.

Comment: Dheeraj can you also give what have you put in the url <your classname/methodname? 
is it separate asp.net mvc controller with a action?

Comment: there you have to put url of your method which will be called on post method. Same what you write inside form post attribute

Comment: Dheeraj only problem is that i am now getting data as null in my controller

Comment: You have to pass data in this format:   data: {attribute: "value"}. and at server side you should have "attribute" as a parameter which will have the value.