# Using @Html.ActionLink to pass parameters to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following @Html.ActionLink() works intermittently. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ServiceSchedules(string businessName, string serviceName, DateTime serviceScheduleStart, DateTime serviceScheduleEnd)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (businessName == null || serviceName == null || serviceScheduleStart == null || serviceScheduleEnd == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        try
        {
            return View(_serviceManager.AddClientSchedule(businessName, serviceName, serviceScheduleStart, serviceScheduleEnd));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
  linkText: "Select date/time slot",
  actionName: "ServiceSchedules",
  controllerName: "Services",
  routeValues: new {
      businessName = item.BusinessName,
      serviceName = item.ServiceName,
      serviceScheduleStart = item.ServiceScheduleStart,
      serviceScheduleEnd = item.ServiceScheduleEnd
  },
  htmlAttributes: null)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not getting to the post endpoint?

Comment: @ZachHutchins It's just not reaching the endpoint of calling the manager method to add to the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC ActionLink and post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method)