# How to pass a Javascript variable via POST , and redirect to a new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JavaScript variable, and I want to send via POST to a PHP page and I want to display the new page. 
I tried this solution, but it seems not work. I have checked within Wireshark, and the variable (key and value) are sent correctly, but the page, doesn't show anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tbID tr").click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
                var value = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();

            });

        });
        function send(value) {
            $.post("newPhp.php", {
                key : value

            }).done(function(data) {
                location.href="newPhp.php";
            });
        }
```

The newPhp.php:`

```
    if(!empty($_POST["key"])){
        $value  = $_POST['key'];`
//something with $value
}
```

So what is the problem with this code ? 
Are there any simpler solution ?

Comment: You're running `newPhp.php` twice. `$.post` sends a `POST` request to it with a parameter. When it replies to that, `location.href` redirects to the page with a `GET` request and no parameters.

Comment: You should either submit the form normally, or the `.done` function should display the output in the current page instead of redirecting.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suppose is the key problem. So how Can I pass the parameter, and display the new page ?

Comment: That's what normal form submission does. Why are you using AJAX?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054705/non-ajax-jquery-post-request

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function send(value) {
    $.post( "newPhp.php",
        {key:value},
        function( data ) {
            location.href="newPhp.php";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work ! The newPhp.php doesn't display what I got from the post.

Comment: This code work. Check what Your ajax response is. And check browser console.

Comment: The problem, is that I open twice the page, but only the first time the post works/sends