# JQuery Datepicker - Send selected date to a new page, using it as a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

### EDIT

I got it working puting the date behind the url to the target site. On the other side I'm using $_GET['val'] to get the value. But this ***way too hacky*** and I'd love to see an more secure solution. But for now it works.

---

**What I'm trying to achieve**

Page 1: 
Showing a datepicker. The user clicks on a date and gets directed to "Page 2".

Page 2:
Showing the previously selected date.

**Whats the problem?**
How do I send the selected date to a new page (so I can store the date in a php variable). Also I want to direct the user to the new page automatically after selecting a date.

---

### *This is what I got so far:*

**index.php** (containing the datepicker)

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {                    
            var date = $('#datepicker').val();  
            alert(date);
            $.post('getdate.php', {'val': dateText});
        }
    });
});
```

**getdate.php**

```
<?php
  $value = $_POST['val'];
  echo "I got your value! $val";
?>
```

The alert shows the selected date, so the variable is containing the date. But I can't get it so send it to my next page.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [non-AJAX jquery POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054705/non-ajax-jquery-post-request)

Answer (score 1):

you are posting dateText...try posting date like:

```
$.post('getdate.php', {'val': date});
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo. But the site stays still the same. How do I make it loading the new page 'getdate.php' displaying the recieved date.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options to make it work. Here are three of them:

1) Send the selected date to page 2 as a query parameter:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {                    
            var date = $('#datepicker').val();  
            window.location.href = 'page2.php?date=' + date;
        }
    });
});
```

2) Put your datepicker insider a form and submit it after date selection.

3) Store the date in session inside your **getdate.php** file:

```
if (!empty($_POST['val'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['current_date'] = $_POST['val'];
}
```

... and check inside your second page:

```
//page2.php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['current_date'])) {
    header('Location:index.php'); //redirect to first page if date not set
}

$selectedDate = $_SESSION['current_date'];
....
```

Choose the one that fits better your problem.

Comment: My datepicker is located in 'index.php'. How could I save it into a session from index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is sending the date to the script **getdate.php**. But you do not see it i the browser because your ajax post does not send the user to the page. For this you would need to direct the script to that page, and one approach would be using a form:

**index.php** should also have a form:

```
<form id="hiddenfrm" action="getdate.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="val" id="val" />
</forms>


<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {                    
            var date = $('#datepicker').val();  
            $('#val').val(date);
            $('hiddenfrm').submit();
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also be as simple as the val parameter is in quotes and I don't think it should be.

```
$.post('getdate.php', {val: date});
```

Comment: are you echoing the correct value you have `echo "I got your value! $val";` and it should be `echo "I got your value! $value";`

Comment: @DefFx The site isn't direkting me to getdate.php. It stays at index.php, but I want to direct the user to getdate.php, after selecting a date, located on the index.php page. And yes, I'm echoing the correct value, but haven't been that far yet to see a result.

Comment: your post method is not going to land a user on that page. The echo in getdate.php will send the results back to the current page. I made successful test by adding a results div to the main page like`<div id="results"></div>` and then a return like `$.post('getdate.php', {'val': date},function( data ) { $( "#results" ).html( data ); });` works just fine.If you send an object back to the page you will need json encode before your echo and in the result you will need `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: you will have to try one of the other methods people suggested here if you are trying to land on getdate.php but my last comment will do the calculations in getdate.php and send the results back to you current page