# How to remove jQuery from this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webhooks

Due to some reason, I don't want to use jQuery in this JavaScript code:

```js
$(function() {
  var url = ; //webhook URL here
  var content = "Hiii";
  var username = "Hi";
  $.post(url, {"content": content, "username": username});
  });
```

Is there any way to convert this into a code that doesn't require jQuery?

Comment: You still want to send `content` and `username`?

Comment: check this post for ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: @KeremCan yes, I want to send the content and username.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: Dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054705/non-ajax-jquery-post-request

Comment: @MasterAdit then you should use form. check links above. your question is duplicate

Comment: @Bassie @ObsidianAge I am not using this code in HTML project. Hence, I can't use phrases like `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can replace the `$()` with something like

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {})`

Secondly if you're only targeting newer browsers you can make use of `fetch`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    var url = ; //webhook URL here
    var content = "Hiii";
    var username = "Hi";
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            content: content,
            username: username,
        })
    });
});
```

or fallback to using plain XHR

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.send({
        content: content,
        username: username,
});
```

Comment: Even if you aren't targeting only newer browsers, it's good to use the modern `fetch` method anyway, because Promises are wonderful - just use a polyfill.

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming that OP want's to get rid of dependencies and if targeting older browsers then OP would need to add a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = "Hiii";
var username = "Hi";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "your API url";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send({"content": content, "username": username});
```

You can use XMLHttpRequest to make AJAX call like above.