# An easy way to post to a URL and not use ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I know $.ajax() can be used to POST to a url but I can't use $.ajax() for my problem. I want the client to POST to a url and have the server redirect to a user to some url (PRG pattern) so therefore, it cannot use XHR requests.

How can I get the client to POST to a url **without** creating a `<form>`? Surely, there's got to be an easier solution than this. [jQuery post request (not AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583703/jquery-post-request-not-ajax)

Comment: without creating "?" ?? You can make a redirection using js, so I don't see why you cannot use ajax...

Comment: Maybe someone smarter than me will contridict me, but in my experience, you need either a form or ajax.  Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery non-AJAX POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524045/jquery-non-ajax-post)

Comment: you need ajax in order to make the call.. you dont necessarily need a form though.. see my answer for an ajax way of doing this.

Comment: @Brad - That solution is simple but it still creates a form.

Comment: @burnt1ce: You are losing the session data during a redirect? I think that is your problem!

Comment: @burnt1ce, Why don't you want to create a form?  It doesn't appear on your page... it's in the background.

Comment: The challenge is not how do I POST to a url. I know I can create an invisible <form> to POST to a url but I had a gut feeling that there would be a better solution. The problem occurs frequently and the solution feels like it came from the web 1.0 days. I was hoping to find a better/cleaner solution. If I can create an AJAX request to POST to a url without creating a <form>, why can't I do the same without using an AJAX request?

Comment: @burnt1ce Because you need to send your data somehow. I understand your problem but I am afraid the is no better solution then an ajax post.

Comment: @PiTheNumber I can still send my data using a POST request without ajax. But I agree that there's possibly no better solution than to create a <form>

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you POST with Ajax, and then whenever it returns, do a Javascript redirect within the callback function? Just have the server provide the URL to redirect to as a response.

Answer (score 2):

You can create and send a form or use ajax. There is no other way I know of.

But why not: First save the data using ajax post and then go to the new page.

```
$.post('youscript.php', function(data) {
  window.location.href = data;
});
```

Otherwise see this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524045/jquery-non-ajax-post) on how to send it with a dynamically created form.

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach is to use jquery and click() events. and passing them as var's in a dataset using data: {data1: datavals}

ill edit this post once the code is written.

**update:**

```
<input type="text" name="data1" id="data1" value="" placeholder="Input text for data 1">
<input type="text" name="data2" id="data2" value="" placeholder="Input text for data 2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        data: {data1: $("#data1").val(), data2: $("#data2").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"

    });
});
```