# Saving json object fo file

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I need to save a json object to a file.
Therefore I'm using another PHP script which writes the data to a file. Data and filename are sent by an ajax POST request.

```
var results = $('results');
var filename = $('#filename').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'jsonWriter.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify([{data: data, filename: filename }]),
    success: function(data) {
        results.html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
        results.html("<p class=\"error\">ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error + "</p>");
    }
});
```

When I monitor the request in Fiddler, it looks fine and the posted data is correct.
However, somehow the error function is invoked. It outputs

```
ERROR: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

I copied the posted JSON data from Fiddler into different online parsers, which ensured it is valid.

Why is the error function invoked anyway?

Comment: And does your PHP script actually return valid JSON? It doesn't seem like it does. Post the PHP code as well. The "dataType" option sets the type of data that is expected to be **returned**, not sent !

Comment: Provide sample data, particularly start and end of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuey/Json Error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967289/jquey-json-error-syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character)

Comment: php reply please ? Also you are waiting for json reply which you try to put it straight into your document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are expecting the server to return text content, since you are applying it with `.html`:

```
success: function(data) {
    results.html(data);
},
```

However, you are telling jQuery to expect JSON data:

```
dataType: "json",
```

jQuery is therefore attempting to parse your content returned from the server as JSON and failing. You need to change `dataType` to either `text` or `html`.