# Can jQuery access the response header for non ajax request

Tags: jquery, response-headers

Is it possible for jQuery to access the `getResponseHeader` or `getAllResponseHeaders` methods for a regular non-ajax request?

I investigated the `onReady` and `onLoad` event but to no luck.

I have some custom headers that contain some debug information an they work great except on non AJAX calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: Might be a good reference for making non-AJAX requests with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149454/non-ajax-get-post-using-jquery-plugin