# In Javascript, what is the motivation or advantage of using var foo = function foo(i) { ... }?

Tags: javascript, function, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

I see that in the answer of

> [In Javascript, why write "var QueryStringToHash = function QueryStringToHash (query) { ... }"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233582/in-javascript-why-write-var-querystringtohash-function-querystringtohash-qu)

which is doing something like

```
var foo = function foo(param) {
  ...
}
```

in that particular case, why do that instead of just using

```
function foo(param) {
  ...
}
```

?  What is the advantage or motivation of doing that?

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)

Comment: There's an in-between that you may have missed: `var foo = function (param) { ... }`. The main differences between that, and using a named function expression, are debugging niceness (mentioned in @Daniel's link) and recursion (only mentioned in passing).

Answer (score 0):

In shortly, if you take the following code, the first example creates a function, named `foo`, the second example creates an anonymous function and assign it to `bar` variable. Besides style, the basic difference is that `foo` can be called, in code, before it's definition (since it's the name of the function); otherwise, `bar` is an undefined variable before it receives the assignment, thus cannot be used before.

```
var foo_result = foo(123); // ok
function foo(param) { /* ... */ }

var bar_result = bar(123); // error: undefined is not a function
var bar = function(param) { /* ... */ }
var bar_result = bar(123); // ok
```

I'd recommend you to read the suggestion of @Pekka.