# mixing javascript function declaration styles

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

Consider two styles of javascript function declarations (out of four, I think):

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

versus

```
var foo = function() {
    // ...
}
```

In many circumstances these will behave the same, and I think I grok the main difference as explained in e.g. these SO questions:

[difference-between-var-foo-function-and-function-foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314434/difference-between-var-foo-function-and-function-foo?lq=1)

[usual-functions-vs-function-variables-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333830/usual-functions-vs-function-variables-in-javascript)

which both have answers linking to this very helpful explanation:

[javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-function-declaration-ambiguity/)

But I would like to combine both styles in one statement; one short/minifiable local variable name (because I will need to refer to it quite often) and one descriptive name (I want to get something friendly out of `.name`).

This is where I get confused. It is as if the act of immediately assigning the function to a variable leaves it undefined under its own name:

```
var f = function foo() {
    // ...
};
console.log( f.name );   // "foo"
console.log( foo.name ); // !? error: foo is not defined ?!
```

So to get to the question: why does this not work? Or, more likely, what might I still be misunderstanding about these two declaration styles?

Note, that the following does *not* result in an error:

```
var f = foo;
function foo() {
    // ...
}
console.log( f.name );   // "foo"
console.log( foo.name ); // "foo"
```

How, exactly, is this different?

PS: I think this is different from this SO question:

[in-javascript-what-is-the-motivation-or-advantage-of-using-var-foo-function-f...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401290/in-javascript-what-is-the-motivation-or-advantage-of-using-var-foo-function-f?lq=1)

which is about a special case of my predicament, where the variable name and function name are the same, i.e.

```
var foo = function foo() {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
var f = function foo () { ... }
```

the scope of `foo` is just the body of the function, *not* the enclosing function. This is mainly useful for creating anonymous recursive functions.

[whats the difference between function foo(){} and foo = function(){}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403121/whats-the-difference-between-function-foo-and-foo-function?lq=1)

recommends against using that notation, because they don't work correctly in some implementations.

Comment: Well that was quick, thanks! So are you saying that the scope of a function's "proper" name is different when it occurs as rvalue in an assignment rather than as a separate statement (see the working snippet below the one with the error)

Comment: It's the difference between a function expression and a function statement.

Comment: Which, by spec, have different effects on the enclosing scope. The answer in your link was helpful, thanks again... I should probably have searched more extensively.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see it. Every function in javascript inherits from Function object and Function object has property .name.

this creates the function object with the name foo in the global space:

```
function foo(){}
```

this creates local anonymous(thus no name) function and assigns is to the variable f which lives in global space:

```
var f = function(){}
```

this creates the function object and assigns it to variable, it doesn't exist in global context, only local to f, the same as above, but assigns the name foo:

```
var f = function foo(){}
```

edit: for better picture consider following

```
(function foo(){console.log("executing foo")})();
(function(){console.log("executing anonymous")})();
```

are both function(objects) in global context - first with name, second without name. If they are created in variable it works the same just context is different.