# jQuery read params from hash in URL and store in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there an extension of jquery to obtain from a set of params:

```
categories[]=Shop+Mac&categories[]=Software&price_max=2799&price_min=24&sort=&page=1
```

a JSON object like:

```
{
   'categories':   ["Shop Mac", "Software"],
   'price_max':    "2799",
   'price_min':    "24",
   'page':         '1'
}
```

...?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/javascript-jquery-param-inverse-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution:

```
// Get args from somewhere
var args = 'categories[]=Shop+Mac&categories[]=Software&price_max=2799&price_min=24&sort=&page=1';

// Set up final object
var output = {}

// Split on & to get groups of key-value pairs
args = args.split('&');

for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

    // Split on = to get separate key from value 
    args[i] = args[i].split('=');

    // Remove square brackets from the key if they exist
    if (/\[\]$/.test(args[i][0])) {
        key = args[i][0].substring(0,(args[i][0].length) - 2);
    } else {
        key = args[i][0]
    }

    // If we haven't visited this key before then set it to a empty array
    if (output[key] === undefined) {
        output[key] = [];
    }

    // Push the value in to the array and remove + symbols whilst we're at it
    output[key].push(args[i][1].replace('+', ' '));

}
```

If you're using Firefox you can:

```
// You can now use output
console.debug(output);
```

And you'll get:

```
categories: ["Shop Mac", "Software"]
page: ["1"] 
price_max: ["2799"]
price_min: ["24"]
sort: [""]
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't decode the result (it just converts `+` to a space).

Comment: I didn't know what the significance of the `+` sign was but I saw that the output removed it so I did too. It would be easy enough to modify this solution to do whatever you want at that point.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery/2880929#2880929) to a similar question that should help you.  I voted to close this as a duplicate of that question, but now I see that there are extra requirements in this one.  When I wrote that answer, I made a version that will handle array-style URL parameters too:

```
(function () {
    var e,
        d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s).replace(/\+/g, " "); },
        q = window.location.search.substring(1),
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;

    while (e = r.exec(q)) {
        if (e[1].indexOf("[") == "-1")
            urlParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
        else {
            var b1 = e[1].indexOf("["),
                aN = e[1].slice(b1+1, e[1].indexOf("]", b1)),
                pN = d(e[1].slice(0, b1));

            if (typeof urlParams[pN] != "object")
                urlParams[d(pN)] = {},
                urlParams[d(pN)].length = 0;

            if (aN)
                urlParams[d(pN)][d(aN)] = d(e[2]);
            else
                Array.prototype.push.call(urlParams[d(pN)], d(e[2]));

        }
    }
})();
```

You can see a working demo here: http://jsbin.com/adali3/2

Sample query string:

> `test=Hello&person[]=jeff&person[]=jim&person[extra]=john&nocache=1290122355841`

Result:

```
{
    "test": "Hello",
    "person": {
        "0": "jeff",
        "1": "jim",
        "length": 2,
        "extra": "john"
    },
    "nocache": "1290100673882"
}
```