# How do I deserialize a big long querystring in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

I'm trying to figure out how to enable the back and forward buttons in my AJAX application, which is dynamic and database driven. To capture the state, I am trapping some values for url, type, and data in an associative array.

I am getting the hash string back from the browser during the 'hashchange' event, I just don't know how to turn it back into an associative array from the encoded query string. Can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The $.param( ) inverse function in JavaScript / jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/the-param-inverse-function-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a [`deserialize`](http://plugins.jquery.com/deserialize/) plugin that might fit the bill.

Alternatively take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/javascript-jquery-param-inverse-function/1131658#1131658) which writes a jQuery function to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

[something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/AVBsj/2/)

```
var hash = 'one=1&two=2',
    split = hash.split('&');

var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    var kv = split[i].split('=');
    obj[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1] ? kv[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ') : kv[1]);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Josiah, that is almost on the money, but the values I serialized have pluses in them for the spaces, etc., and have been encoded for submission. The jQuery deserialize plugin is working, except that I can't now decode some of the values.

Comment: @AKWF - I updated the fiddle and the post to decode, and replace `+` characters.

Comment: I ended up finding the <a href="http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm">URL Decoder</a> plugin. It worked right away, some of the internals are probably almost identical with what you did here. Thanks for your help Josiah.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getQuery() {
    var query = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var queryArray = [];
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        queryArray.push([pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
    return queryArray;
}
```

Comment: This creates an array, not an "associative" array or rather, object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. It looks like a call to $.bbq.getState() does most of it for me. But I will need that deserialize method later...