# The opposite of jQuery.param()

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you serialize a object with `$.param()` how do i get it back?

in php there is `parse_str` but i didn't find anything like it in javascript.

**TL&DR**:
Turns out that `parse_str` has been ported to javascript:
http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str/

Comment: The other question is related to a serialized form, i'm talking about objects here...

Comment: not sure why this is still closed, its not a duplicate (at least not to the linked question). Anyway, this is what i was looking for: http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_str/

Answer (score 2):

Check this : [Javascript / Jquery: $.param( ) inverse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/javascript-jquery-param-inverse-function).

You can also go for [Deserializer of Jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/deserialize/).

> jquery.deserialize is a very simple
>   jQuery plugin providing 'deserialize'
>   functionality to a form elements.

Comment: this should be voted to close instead.

Comment: @Daniel : I voted it to close it. Btw, I also added another useful link :)

Comment: i tried all functions and the desirializer, none of them could deserialize/unparam an object...
If there is something nested, they all screw it up

Comment: In response to Florian Fida, this worked for me on the project I'm working on: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re4vra5o/).

Comment: Here's an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/re4vra5o/1/

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if it's included in jquery, but look at http://www.json.org. There is file that you can use and do JSON.parse(). I think firefox has native support for it, but I don't think IE does.

Comment: No its not JSON...
but it looks like i have to switch to JSON in that case