# jQuery Mobile Data in URL

Tags: jquery, mobile, hashbang

Using jQuery Mobile, how could I create hashbang URLs such as `#!/value_1/value_2` and be able to read both of these values, assuming that both parameters will always be in the same order.

One caveat is that this is being powered by a one page structure, so I'm not linking to an external page.

Comment: This question might help you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629776/jquery-mobile-and-query-parameters-for-hashbang-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile automatically maps hashbangs to page element ids (faux pages) by default. First you need to disable this behavior.

Then you need have a custom logic which reads windows.location.hash and takes action on it either when

- the site is loaded
- individual faux page is openend (onpageshow JQM event)

Creating links happens like you would create links normally - just set a href value.

Here is more info:

[jQuery Mobile and "query parameters" for hashbang navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629776/jquery-mobile-and-query-parameters-for-hashbang-navigation)

Comment: If that's the only way, then so be it :) Cheers!