# how to get match id by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get match (id) by jquery 
I want to get (id) in (href) Between (span)

If the code
here

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='zero'>
  <span>
   <a href="http//google&id=222.com">123</a>
   <a>hgi</a>
  </span>
   <span>
   <a href="http//google&id=111.com">123</a>
   <a>hgi</a>
  </span>
   <span>
   <a href="http//google&id=333.com">123</a>
   <a>hgi</a>
  </span>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jquery**

```
$(".zero span").each(function(){
$(this).find("a").attr("href").match(/id=/);

});
```

but Error >_<
why ?
and
how ?

i want

```
id=222
id= 333
id= 111
```

Comment: if it's dynamically generated why not just use an actual ID, i.e. <a href="http//google&id=333.com" id="333">link</a>, then target that?

Comment: If the URLs are sufficiently varied and complicated, you might want to try using the deparam function [referenced here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/the-param-inverse-function-in-javascript-jquery) instead of writing your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your `<a />` elements do not have an `href` property. `attr()` will return `undefined` in this case. When trying to call `match()` on `undefined`, JavaScript throws an error.

Fix it with:

```
$(".zero span").each(function(){
    href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if (href !== undefined) {
        href.match(/id=/);
    }
});
```

Or change the selector to include `a[href]`.

Outside:

```
$(".zero span a[href]").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href").match(/id=/);        
});
```

Inside:

```
$(".zero span").each(function(){
    $(this).find("a[href]").attr("href").match(/id=/);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
$(".zero span").each(function(){
   alert($(this).find("a").attr("href").match(/id=\d+/)[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(this).find("a").attr("href").match(/id=.*/);
```

That will match id and all characters after.