# Convert the Query string parameters to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to convert the query string parameters to a JSON object

Code I was written

```
var actualappt = {
    RoomId: 1, HotelId: 29, BookingStartDate: Sept 26 2014, BookingEndDate: Sept 26 2014 , BookingStatusId: '1', BookingTypeId: '1', DepositAmount: 3000, NoOfRooms: 2, UnitPrice: 4000,
    Customers: { GuestName: rk, MobileNo: 5656566555, Email: rk@gmail.com, Address: hyd }, Payment_Mode_Id: 4
};

var stringsata = JSON.stringify(actualappt);

var queryString = $.param(actualappt);
```

Now I am able to convert JSON object to  query string  and sending to next page, in my page I want  reverse process i.e from query string to JSON object

Comment: FYI: That is not JSON.

Comment: @epascarello Correct. This is a normal object.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/the-param-inverse-function-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
var actualappt = {
    RoomId: 1, HotelId: 29, BookingStartDate: "Sept 26 2014", BookingEndDate:"Sept 26 2014" , BookingStatusId: '1', BookingTypeId: '1', DepositAmount: 3000, NoOfRooms: 2, UnitPrice: 4000,
    Customers: { GuestName: "rk", MobileNo: 5656566555, Email: "rk@gmail.com", Address: "hyd"}, Payment_Mode_Id: 4
};

var stringsata = JSON.stringify(actualappt);

var queryString = $.param(actualappt);
var recoveredParams = {};
var queryString = decodeURIComponent(queryString)
$.each(queryString.split('&'), function(key, value){
    var item= value.split('=');
    recoveredParams[item[0]] = item[1]; 
});
console.log(recoveredParams)
```

Comment: i modify "actualappt" to correctly Javascript Object

Comment: If I convert recoveredParams to JSON.stringify(actualappt) Customers[GuestName]:rk like this getting , is it possible to convert   " Customers: { GuestName: "rk", MobileNo: 5656566555, Email: "rk@gmail.com", Address: "hyd"}" like this @foued611

Comment: it only posible is valid JS Object like this:  { Customers: { GuestName: "rk", MobileNo: 5656566555, Email: "rk@gmail.com", Address: "hyd"}}