# Is it possible to send object in url jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, url, object

```
data.push({
    name: name,
    age: age,
    address: address,
    contactnumber: contactnumber

});

var url = '../reports/student.php?data='+data;
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

`../reports/student.php?data=[object%20Object]`

Above is an object i want to send to another page so i can retrieve it and use it on the next page to generate a report. The url is looking like the one above i am not sure if this is possible and if possible how can i get the value of each data in the object.If not possible please point me to the right direction any idea is ap

Comment: Use `POST` with `data`  as JSON in the body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you definetly want to use `GET` request, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var url = '../reports/student.php?data='+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
```

But better way will be a `POST` request.

You also can use `jQuery.param()`:

```
var data = {
  name: 'yourname',
  age: 1,
}

var params = jQuery.param(data) // 'name=yourname&age=1'
var url = '../reports/student.php?'+ params;
```

Comment: it is ok if i dont stringify the data before sending i mean i want to do all retrieving in the next page?i mean i dont want to put stingify in the sending of data in url is it possible and how can i get the data now that i have sent it using jquery not php

Comment: my question is how will i get the value now in second page?

Comment: there is simple function for parsing `get` params by JS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: should i pass the entire url to the function of just the `data`?

Comment: for get a `data` param you call like this: `getParameterByName('data')`

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements with name/value properties.

The doc also states, that

> If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

So in your case:

```
var url = '../reports/student.php?' + jQuery.param(serializeArray(data));
```

To unserialize you should use [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)'s [deparam](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) function, as per cce's answer in this SO question: [The $.param( ) inverse function in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/the-param-inverse-function-in-javascript-jquery).

Comment: how can i retrieve these value in the second page?

Comment: what i am getting in url is `?data=undefined=`