# Select URL parameters with jquery and add them to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a url link:

```
http://mywebsite.org/product/page?var_one=result1&var_two=result2&var_three=result3&var_four=result4
```

The parameters are dynamic so it will not be static numbers. 
In my example are 4, but maybe less or more. 
 I have a jquery code that pre selects a dropdown:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1");  
});
```

Now I want to, depending on the url parameters above to populate jquery code like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1"); 
    $("#var_two").val("result2"); 
    $("#var_three").val("result3"); 
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131630/the-param-inverse-function-in-javascript-jquery you can use the code there to load the parameters and set them one-by-one to the relevant variables

Comment: to parse url properly in javascript i suggest you to use uri.js https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

Comment: you want to create dynamic inputs (with dynamic id's) and values. check my answer update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to form a array of key value pair based on the url and use `forEach` to loop through the array and add the value to the id using `.text()`

Hope this helps!

```js
var a = "http://mywebsite.org/product/page?var_one=result1&var_two=result2&var_three=result3&var_four=result4"

var query = a.split('?')[1] //extract query param
var queries = query.split(/&/g) //extract key value pairs from query param
queries.forEach(function(el){ //loop through the key value pair
  var newElm = '<div id="' + el.split('=')[0] + '">'+el.split('=')[1]+'</div>' //create new elm
  $('body').append(newElm) //append into DOM Body
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. 
What I want is: 
Take the first parameter var_one=result1 
Var one should be the inserted in the jquery script as ID #var_one, and result1 should be inserted as value. 

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1");
});  

If there are more parameters, jquery should be populated with others as well: 
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1"); 
    $("#var_two").val("result2"); 
    $("#var_three").val("result3"); 
    .
    .
    .
});

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. Had to modify a little for my code but it did what I was looking for. :)

Comment: This is my final code if someone else may need: 

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  
   var a = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

var query = a.split('?')[1] ;//extract query param
var queries = query.split(/&/g) ;//extract key value pairs from query param
queries.forEach(function(el){ //loop through the key value pair
    $("#"+ el.split('=')[0] +"").val(""+el.split('=')[1]+"");
});
  
    
});

Comment: @ArensMyzyri Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to retrieve URL-parameters:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    if (sParam != undefined && sParam.length > 0) {
        var sPageHref = window.location.href;
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = (sPageURL.length != '') ? sPageURL.split('&') : sPageHref.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
          var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
  } else {
    var sPageURL = document.location.pathname.split('&');
    var sParameterName = sPageURL[0];
    return sParameterName;
  }
}
```

If you specify a parameter, like `GetURLParameter('something')` it will fetch that. If you just use `GetURLParameter()` it will fetch the link used, ie `/index.php` or whatever.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. 
What I want is: 
Take the first parameter var_one=result1 
Var one should be the inserted in the jquery script as ID #var_one, and result1 should be inserted as value. 

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1");
});  

If there are more parameters, jquery should be populated with others as well: 
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#var_one").val("result1"); 
    $("#var_two").val("result2"); 
    $("#var_three").val("result3"); 
    .
    .
    .
});

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: to answer your question correctly as i understood you need to convert url parameters to JSON then use for loop and use keys, values to fill inputs values. so inputs are and values dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  String.prototype.allParams = function() {
    return JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(this.split("?")[1]).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"') + '"}')
  }


  var url = "http://mywebsite.org/product/page?var_one=result1&var_two=result2&var_three=result3&var_four=result4";
  //var url = location.href
  var params = url.allParams();

  for (var k in params) {
    if ($("#" + k).length) $("#" + k).val(params[k]);
    //if input id not exist append to body or any container
    //you can remove next line
    else $("body").append("<input value='" + params[k] + "'/>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this prototype `url.param("param");` to get parameter value.

```js
String.prototype.param = function(str) {
  e = this.indexOf("?" + str + "=") > -1 ? "?" + str + "=" : "&" + str + "=";
  return this.indexOf(e) == -1 ? undefined : this.split(e)[1].split("&")[0];
}

var url = "http://mywebsite.org/product/page?var_one=result1&var_two=result2&var_three=result3&var_four=result4";

console.log(url.param("var_one")); //result1

console.log(location.href.param("param")); //undefined
```