# Javascript: Get param value from x-www-form-urlencoded request

Tags: javascript, http

How can I get a param value from a 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' request?

Like this response:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

How can I do something like above?

```
var valueOfParam1 = request.body.params['param1']
```

Comment: nodejs backend?

Comment: Java backend. But I'm trying to get this value in an Angular incerteptor before send the request. So the backend is irrelevant

Comment: Well to start with you're the one sending the values right? why wait to intercept when it's generated from your end? secondly do you already have access to it when intercepted? and you simply want to transform into an object like manner right?

Comment: I send the values. But this interceptor catch multiple requests and I need to identify witch request it is before I send. I have the acces to the body string but I'm not knowing how to get one specifc param

Comment: okay I will share a code, someone wrote specifically for this, I would have shared a library u wrote that's similar but I wrote it with cookie in mind, but can still be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a quick solution done by someone here on stackoverflow check his link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131651/8594737

You can also check my library tho it serves for a different purpose, but might be useful to understand and explore incase of a more complex scenario

https://github.com/zico4reel/conversionTracker

I hope these links are helpful